# Same Domino server name but different IP address in same environment

Tags: ibm-domino

We decided to change our physical Domino Server with a new one. In order to prevent current server from being un-accessible while we configure the new one, we plan to up the new Domino server which has the same domino server name with the existing one, only the IP will be different.

For example:

**Existing domino server**

Name : Notes Server/_Org

IP : 10.8.8.**50**

**New domino server**

Name : Notes Server/_Org

IP : 10.8.8.**51**

When the new server is up and run smoothly, we will shut down the current server and change the new server IP address to 10.8.8.**50**

Is it possible ?

And if its possible , is it a good practice or there is a better way to do this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never a good Idea to have two different machines run the same domino server at the same time in the same network.

Domino databases are not to be copied while the server runs, that means: During copy- process you need to shutdown the existing domino server.

The time needed for copying the data around is the biggest time in your whole process, so downtime will not decrease significantly by doing what you want to do.

I always use this approach:

1. start setup.exe in the new Domino, without starting the domino after installation
2. install fixpacks / language packs / etc. as needed to make it the same version as the original one
3. Shutdown domino on existing server and make sure, that the services do not start anymore.
4. copy over the complete data- directory and -optional- the notes.ini from program directory
5. Switch hostnames and IPs of the two servers
6. Start domino on new hostname. If paths are the same and notes.ini copied, it will start exactly as the other was, otherwise the server has to be configured (usually 5 Minutes)